# Facebook login redirect uri error: url blocked, redirect failed

Tags: reactjs, facebook

What is the problem:

Trying to set up login with FB with React. It is working as normal in desktop view via a dialog. But it displays URL blocked when using mobile view, since it uses a separate page.

What have I tried?

1. I have included redirect URI in facebook developer page under Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.
   [image]
2. I inspected facebook url, and included the specific uri path in the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.
   [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use **react-facebook-login** you have to put:

`disableMobileRedirect={true}`

[image]